# using goto keyword in C

Tags: c, goto

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a=5;
  begin:
  if(a)
       printf("%d\n",a);
   a--;
   goto begin;
   return 0;
 }
```

When a becomes 0 then if condition will not execute then why the output is going to be infinty in this code means

output -

```
 5
 4
 3
 2
 1
 0
-1
-2
and so on endless
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Why the if condition is being executed even when a becomes 0

Comment: I don't think you copied your code *exactly* as you compiled it.

Comment: The `if` doesn't trigger when `i` is 0 for me...

Comment: @PP its same buddy, i am getting endless output for the same code, you can check it

Comment: The code works as expected. Does not print 0 like in your output.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Are you sure that you correctly compiled the source?

Comment: guys got my thinking mistake, yep its not printing 0, starting from 5 it goes on endless except printing 0

Comment: ... it's not really related to "using goto keyword"

Comment: @AmanSingh then theres no real question here

Comment: Shouldn't this be deleted? This will not be helpful for anybody in the current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the program really does print `0` for you then there might be a serious problem with your compiler (or even your machine...). My suspicion is that it doesn't print `0`, but your question is really why the program loops infinitely.

This is because the `if`-body only contains the print statement. So when `a` reaches 0 it isn't printed but the lines

```
a--;
goto begin;
```

are still executed. The machine will obey, go back to `begin` and the loop continues. The quickest fix is to put braces around *all* the statements you want executed when `a != 0`:

```
if(a){
    printf("%d\n",a);
    a--;
    goto begin;
}

return 0;
```

This will make the program only loop until `a` is 0, after which it returns.

But the real problem is: don't use `goto` (for this)! This is a perfect situation to use a [`while` loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop):

```
while(a--){
    printf("%d\n", a);
}

return 0;
```

(The braces around the `while`-body are not even strictly necessary here, but just good practice)

Comment: Did you mean `while(a--)`?

Comment: That does make more sense

Answer (score 1):

Its because after the `if` the `goto` statement is again executed and then the value of `a` has already become other than `0` . Now, again you get the `goto` statement and therefore `if` goes on executing and printing negative values.

Look at it this way :-

The statement

> `printf("%d\n",a);`

is executed only when condition in `if` is true. TRUE here refers to anything not equal to `0` so, the `printf` is not executed when `a` is `0`, while it executes for any other value. Now,  `a--` and `goto` are executed outside `if` so they are executed again and again making the condition in `if` true always and negative values are printed infinitely.

Nevertheless,

My question is , why are you using `goto`?

Comment: just checking its working, that's it, actually i am learning C and thank you all for the help

Comment: @AmanSingh Keep in mind that unless you have a very good reason for that, you should not use goto. (And you don't probably have a very good reason for that if you just started learning C.)

Comment: @AmanSingh its very old style almost obsolete. Anyway:)

Comment: Got it guys, and H2CO3 if we have to send the execution back to any part of the program what should i use ?

Comment: @AmanSingh Loops. While, for, do-while...

Comment: Oh come on!! I haven't said it prints 0 why the downvote on my answer. Please explain yourselves.

Comment: Seriously, the downvote was lightning fast without even looking at my answer properly. Can't find out where and when I wrote it prints 0. Just escaped a stroke LOL :D . And despite of writing `0` in output OP clearly states that `if` will not execute .

Answer (score 0):

```
if a==1 -> Evaluates to TRUE
if a==0 -> Evaluates to FALSE
if a==-1 -> Evaluates to TRUE
```

etc.

Therefore it will display numbers in descending order, except 0 which will not display.